# (C QUESTION) Whenever my program runs it gets overloaded with memory. Basically it returns a memory error

Tags: c, sockets, networking

So im running a program and I think I messed up the code, whenever it runs it gets overloaded with memory. Basically it returns a memory error, I think it relates to the mutex.

It basically means that you're accessing memory that you're not supposed to be accessing and I'm trying to figure out why it's doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "headers/queue.h"
#include "headers/main.h"
#include "headers/connection.h"

void bruter_queue_ip(char *address)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    for(int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
    {
        if(!queue[i].queued)
        {
            ATOMIC_INC(&left_in_queue);
            strcpy(queue[i].address, address);
            queue[i].queued = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void *handle_queued()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(processing <= ACTUAL_MAX_CONS)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
            {
                if(queue[i].queued)
                {
                    start_connection(queue[i].address, NULL);

                    queue[i].queued = 0;
                    memset(queue[i].address, 0, 16);
                    ATOMIC_DEC(&left_in_queue);
                }

                if(processing >= ACTUAL_MAX_CONS)
                    break;
            }
        }

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Also please take some time to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch possible crashes, and locate when and where in your code they happen. As well as learn how to use *compiler sanitizers* to aid in fining memory errors (for example, if building with GCC then add the argument `-fsanitize=undefined,address`).

Comment: And a little note about the code: Please don't use global variables. Those are a bad habit that almost never is needed. Instead of passing only the data to be processed by the thread, pass a pointer to a structure containing all that's needed for the thread to work, including pointers to mutexes, arrays, and the actual data).

Comment: What's in `start_connection()`? Why do you need `1,000,000` connections?